# Accessing files within directories using archive.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I am currently trying to pull out some information from a zip archive without fully extracting it to the disk. The zip archives are in a standard format:

```
myfile.zip
   - myfile.json
   - myfile.geojson
   - images/
      - image1.jpeg
      - image2.jpeg
```

I am using archive_io.dart to access the info in the archive, but I am stumped as to how I can get the image out of the `images/` subdir. So far I have implemented a function to open the zip archive:

```
Archive _openArchive(String filePath) {
    final inputStream = InputFileStream(filePath);
    final archive = ZipDecoder().decodeBuffer(inputStream);
    return archive;
    /* for (ArchiveFile file in archive.files) {
      if (file.isFile) {
        if (file.name.contains('json') && !file.name.contains('geojson')) {
          return file;
        }
      }
    } */
  }
```

This then gets utilized in another function that reads out the data from `myfile.json` and `myfile.geojson`.

```
void _extractArchiveData() async {
    await _pickFiles(); //from file_picker.dart
    FinalizedHike? outHike; //a class that I use for this project
    var absPath = _file?.first.path.toString(); //the path of the zip archive from the file picker
    //print(absPath);
    if (absPath != null) {
      widget.filePath = absPath;
      Archive openArchive = _openArchive(absPath); //open the zip file
      try {
        for (ArchiveFile file in openArchive.files) {
          //reads in the data from myfile.json and myfile.geosjon
          if (file.isFile) {
            if (file.name.contains('json') && !file.name.contains('geojson')) {
              var hikeData = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(file.content));
              uploadHike = FinalizedHike.fromJson(hikeData);
            } else if (file.name.contains('geojson')) {
              geoJson = jsonDecode(utf8.decode(file.content));
            } else if (!file.isFile) {
              // Code to go into the images/ subdir and pull out a specific image based off 
              // of a file name that I would pass in.
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        print('error ${e}');
      }
    }
  }
```

I am unsure if this is even possible. To create the zip archive I also use archive_io.dart, using the following fxn:

```
  void _createArchive() {
    try {
      var encoder = ZipFileEncoder();
      encoder.zipDirectory(Directory(_saveAsFileName!),
          filename: '$_saveAsFileName.zip');
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

I believe that this does recursive compression, so that the `images/` subdir is also compressed. I have considered trying to pass `images/` as an `InputStream` that could be used by `ZipDecoder.decodeBuffer()` but I am unsure how I would do that. Is there a way to convert an `ArchiveFile` to an `InputStream`?

Answer (score 1):

I did some more digging and figured out that you can access the files directly, and their name will just be notated like `images/image1.jpeg`. To double check you can use:

```
for (final file in archive) {
   print(file.name);
}
```

returns

```
myfile.json
myfile.geojson
images/image1.jpeg
images/image2.jpeg
```